# how to fix Angular not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using strict mode and `Angular 1.4.7` , I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:strictdi] function($scope, $element, $attrs, mouseCapture) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
```

The angular generated url for the error is:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi?p0=function($scope,%20$element,%20$attrs,%20mouseCapture

And the following is the service

```
angular.module('mouseCapture', [])

//
// Service used to acquire 'mouse capture' then receive dragging events while the mouse is captured.
//
.factory('mouseCapture', function ($rootScope) {

    //
    // Element that the mouse capture applies to, defaults to 'document' 
    // unless the 'mouse-capture' directive is used.
    //
    var $element = document; 

    //
    // Set when mouse capture is acquired to an object that contains 
    // handlers for 'mousemove' and 'mouseup' events.
    //
    var mouseCaptureConfig = null;

    //
    // Handler for mousemove events while the mouse is 'captured'.
    //
    var mouseMove = function (evt) {

        if (mouseCaptureConfig && mouseCaptureConfig.mouseMove) {

            mouseCaptureConfig.mouseMove(evt);

            $rootScope.$digest();
        }
    };

    //
    // Handler for mouseup event while the mouse is 'captured'.
    //
    var mouseUp = function (evt) {

        if (mouseCaptureConfig && mouseCaptureConfig.mouseUp) {

            mouseCaptureConfig.mouseUp(evt);

            $rootScope.$digest();
        }
    };

    return {

        // 
        // Register an element to use as the mouse capture element instead of 
        // the default which is the document.
        //
        registerElement: function(element) {

            $element = element;
        },

        //
        // Acquire the 'mouse capture'.
        // After acquiring the mouse capture mousemove and mouseup events will be 
        // forwarded to callbacks in 'config'.
        //
        acquire: function (evt, config) {

            //
            // Release any prior mouse capture.
            //
            this.release();

            mouseCaptureConfig = config;

            // 
            // In response to the mousedown event register handlers for mousemove and mouseup 
            // during 'mouse capture'.
            //
            $element.mousemove(mouseMove);
            $element.mouseup(mouseUp);
        },

        //
        // Release the 'mouse capture'.
        //
        release: function () {

            if (mouseCaptureConfig) {

                if (mouseCaptureConfig.released) {
                    //
                    // Let the client know that their 'mouse capture' has been released.
                    //
                    mouseCaptureConfig.released();
                }

                mouseCaptureConfig = null;
            }

            $element.unbind("mousemove", mouseMove);
            $element.unbind("mouseup", mouseUp);
        },
    };
})

//
// Directive that marks the mouse capture element.
//
.directive('mouseCapture', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',

    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, mouseCapture) {

        // 
        // Register the directives element as the mouse capture element.
        //
        mouseCapture.registerElement($element);

    },
  };
})
;
```

How do i fix this error

Comment: For others like me, I ran into this because I was using an older version of the Angular Batarang Chrome Extension which was lacking annotations.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi) it looks like you need to declare all dependency injections in string array.

There are other ways but normally I would do it like this:

```
controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', 'mouseCapture',
  function($scope, $element, $attrs, mouseCapture) {
    ...
  }
]
```

One of the reason we do this is because when we try to minify this js file, variable names would be reduced to one or 2 characters, and DI needs the exact name to find the services. By declaring DI in a string array, angular can match services with their minified variable name. For this reason, the string array and the function arguments need EXACT MATCHING in number and order.

---

*Update:*

If you are following [John Papa's Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection), you should do it like this:

```
controller: MouseCaptureController,
...

MouseCaptureController.$inject = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', 'mouseCapture'];

function MouseCaptureController($scope, $element, $attrs, mouseCapture) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This worked for my directive as well :) I assume it would work for any Provider (e.g. Service, Factory)

Comment: One question, how to find which service is the culprit? In my scenario, Angular shows a call stack that is only filled with angular methods calls. I can't find *what service*.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati normally angular errors come with links like `https://docs.angularjs.org/error/...`, click inside and read the error message. Sometimes the real error is a few layer inside.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. However when I click on it, the entire callstack is related to anguarjs. I don't know which part of my code brought me here.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Sometimes angular fails to show meaningful error when it can't parse your template. Or you can paste your error link here?

Comment: one question, I export a controller as a module and use/import it in bar.component.js like: let {..., controller: controller,...} and I get the same error, how can I solve that?

Comment: I'm also getting this error when using a class:
`angular.module('my.system').provider(
 'ISupportService',
 class ISupportProvider implements IServiceProvider {...`
And if I'm turning it into a function that returns an object I get this error:
`TypeError: Function.prototype.bind.apply(...) is not a constructor`

Comment: @GarfieldKlon not sure if you should put a class on the second argument, it should be a function with specific things expected inside https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe

Answer (score 9):

The code says:

> $injector:strictdi

There is an error with the dependency injection
In the documentation for this error:

> Strict mode throws an error whenever a service tries to use implicit annotations

You should try to switching to:

```
.factory('mouseCapture', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {...}]);
```

syntax, whenever in strict mode.

Comment: Thanks, this was however not enough. I needed to also add the notation to the controller as @lcycool showed

Comment: yes, totally. You should use this explicit syntax anywhere there is a dependency injection and you are using strict mode.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `'ngInject'` to the first line of your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

adding 'ngInject' was the answer the worked for me. Actually I am using typescript with angularjs, and adding  /*@ngInject*/ right before the constructor did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely try catch caused this error for me.

```
try {
    console.log("test");
} catch {
    console.log("err");
}
```

had to be changed to

```
try {
    console.log("test");
} catch (err) {
    console.log("err");
}
```